# Query another table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pull all the values from a particular column in another table. My goal is to take a handful of different tables and put particular columns from each of them into a single, collated table.

For example, let's say I have tables about different kinds of objects

```
FRUITS

name         flavor
banana       savory
orange       sweet
peach        sweet
```

```
PETS

name         lifespan
dog          long
fish         short
cat          long
```

Imagine that I now want to make a third table with the name column from fruits and pets.

```
COLLATED

name      source 
banana    fruits
orange    fruits
peach     fruits
dog       pets
fish      pets
cat       pets
```

I tried to install the powerpivot add-in to do this, but I wasn't sure how to do it with a Mac. I'd prefer to use any "table connection" features that Excel offers in case that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of ideas from both @Ike and @JosWoolley great answers would be this:

```
=LET(
n,{"Fruits","Pets","Cars"},
w,(tblFruits[Name],tblPets[Name],tblCars[Name]),
y,COUNTA(w),
s,SEQUENCE(AREAS(w)*y,,0),
q,1+QUOTIENT(s,y),
z,CHOOSE({1,2},IFERROR(INDEX(w,1+MOD(s,y),,q),""),INDEX(n,q)),
FILTER(z,INDEX(z,0,1)<>""))
```

For a new table, the table name would be added to the `n` variable and the column/range to the `w` variable without the need to edit the rest of the formula.

**Edit #1**

Adding more columns can get tricky using this approach but it can be done. For example having an extra 'Price' column in all tables would require something like this:

```
=LET(
n,{"Fruits","Pets","Cars"},
w,(tblFruits[Name],tblPets[Name],tblCars[Name]),
p,(tblFruits[Price],tblPets[Price],tblCars[Price]),
y,COUNTA(w),
s,SEQUENCE(AREAS(w)*y,,0),
q,1+QUOTIENT(s,y),
z,CHOOSE({1,2,3},IFERROR(INDEX(w,1+MOD(s,y),,q),""),INDEX(n,q),IFERROR(INDEX(p,1+MOD(s,y),,q),"")),
FILTER(z,INDEX(z,0,1)<>""))
```

where you have an extra `p` variable and the `CHOOSE` is updated to reflect the new values. Of course, you could change the order of the columns  in the `CHOOSE` by either changing the order of the 3 parts or by simply  changing the numbers in the `{1,2,3}` array (e.g. `{1,3,2}`).

Comment: How do I add more columns using this solution? Assume there was another column, for example, called price and the pets had a price to adopt and the fruits had a price to buy. I tried adding another variable and called it price and added tblFruits[Price], tblPets[Price] and so on but that errored out

Comment: I tried adding them to the w variable, but it looks like that appends to the bottom of the new table as opposed to adding in the data as a separate column

Comment: @Cauder Hi, just added an edit section to address your question.

Answer (score 3):

`=LET(w,(tblFruits[name],tblPets[name],tblCars[name]),x,AREAS(w),y,COUNTA(w),z,IFERROR(INDEX(w,1+MOD(SEQUENCE(x*y,,0),y),,1+INT(SEQUENCE(x*y,,0)/y)),""),FILTER(z,z<>""))`

Amend the table column names as required, adding in as many as required.

This should work for reasonably small ranges, though `x*y` could certainly be improved as a lower bound.

Agreed with Ike that a recursive lambda would probably be of help here.

Comment: Nice solution. I would also replace ```INT(SEQUENCE(x*y,,0)/y)``` with ```QUOTIENT(SEQUENCE(x*y,,0),y)``` to be consistent with the ```MOD``` used to get the row. Maybe even create a new variable so that you don't repeat the sequence. Something like ```=LET(w,(…),x,AREAS(w),y,COUNTA(w),s,SEQUENCE(x*y,,0),z,IFERROR(INDEX(w,1+MOD(s,y),,1+QUOTIENT(s,y)),""),FILTER(z,z<>""))```. +1. It would be nice if you could adapt it to also retrieve the source as the second column as per OP's question and Ike's answer

Comment: this is indeed better - as you only have to adjust `w` if there are more than two, three, ... tables.

Comment: @CristianBuse Thanks. Nice call re `QUOTIENT` and `SEQUENCE`. As for the table names, potentially messy, unless you've thought of a nice solution? Without hard-coding the table names as Ike did, if all relevant column names were "name" then you could try `=LET(a,{"Fruits","Pets","Cars"},b,COUNTA(a),c,INDIRECT("tbl"&a&"[name]"),d,MAX(SUBTOTAL(3,c)),e,T(OFFSET(c,SEQUENCE(d,,0),)),f,e&"|"&a,g,SEQUENCE(b*d,,0),h,INDEX(f,1+MOD(g,d),1+QUOTIENT(g,d)),i,FIND("|",h),j,MID(h,i^{0,1}+{0,1},i-{1,0}),FILTER(j,INDEX(j,,1)<>""))` though such indirect, volatile set-ups are far from ideal!

Comment: Of course, that's also assuming that all tables are named consistently "tbl___"

Comment: Correction. That `MID` part was all wrong. `=LET(a,{"Fruits","Pets","Cars"},b,COUNTA(a),c,INDIRECT("tbl"&a&"[name]"),d,MAX(SUBTOTAL(3,c)),e,CELL("contents",OFFSET(c,SEQUENCE(d,,0),)),f,e&"|"&a,g,SEQUENCE(b*d,,0),h,INDEX(f,1+MOD(g,d),1+QUOTIENT(g,d)),i,FIND("|",h),j,MID(h,i^{0,1}+{0,1},i^{1,9}-1),FILTER(j,INDEX(j,,1)<>""))`

Comment: Indeed, I avoid volatile formulas because in my view the gains worth less than the issues that come with using them. An idea would be this: ```=LET(n,{"Fruits","Pets","Cars"},w,(tblFruits[Name],tblPets[Name],tblCars[Name]),y,COUNTA(w),s,SEQUENCE(AREAS(w)*y,,0),q,1+QUOTIENT(s,y),z,CHOOSE({1,2},IFERROR(INDEX(w,1+MOD(s,y),,q),""),INDEX(n,q)),FILTER(z,INDEX(z,0,1)<>""))```. This would be combination of both your and Ike's ideas. I will actually post this as a community answer.

Answer (score 2):

I added two tables to a sheet: tblFruits and tblPets.

Then you can put the following formula in any cell on the same sheet or another sheet.

```
=LET(
     a,CHOOSE({1,2},tblFruits[name],"Fruits"),
     b,CHOOSE({1,2},tblPets[name],"Pets"),
     rowIndex,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a) + ROWS(b)),
     colIndex,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(a)),
     IF(rowIndex<=ROWS(a),
       INDEX(a,rowindex,colIndex),
       INDEX(b,rowindex-ROWS(a),colIndex)
      )
)
```

The first four rows of the formula are used to retrieve variables that are then used in the final IF-function:

`a` and `b` will return "virtual" arrays of each name column plus the "new" column giving the type.

`rowIndex` returns a single array {1,2,...(number of rows of both tables)}

`colIndex` returns an array that is build of the number of columns - in this case 2 (name and type)

These variables are used in the `IF`-formula:
Think of it as a `For i = 1 to Ubound(rowIndex)`-loop.

If the first value from the `rowIndex`-Array is smaller than the number of rows of `tblFruits`,

- then `INDEX`-result is based on virtual array `a`,
- if not the rowindex for `b` is calculated and `INDEX`-result is based on virtual array `b`.

The result is a *spill-down array* - you can use a filter on it. Just add a header row and add filter.

But you won't be able to create a table based on it.
Therefore you will have to use VBA to create the combined data.

This would be the formula with a third table:

```
=LET(
a,CHOOSE({1,2},tblFruits[Name],"Fruits"),
b,CHOOSE({1,2},tblPets[name],"Pets"),
c,CHOOSE({1,2},tblRooms[name],"Rooms"),
rowIndex,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+ROWS(b)+ROWS(c)),
colIndex,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(a)),
IF(rowIndex<=ROWS(a),
         INDEX(a,rowIndex,colIndex),
         IF(rowIndex<=ROWS(a) + ROWS(b),
         INDEX(b,rowIndex-ROWS(a),colIndex),
INDEX(c,rowIndex-(ROWS(a)+ROWS(b)),colIndex))))
```

Comment: Please see my edits to the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna add a 50 pt bounty once it becomes available

Comment: My use case has five or ten different tables. Would I update the last line to something like thisH `INDEX(h,rowIndex-(ROWS(a)+ROWS(b) + rows(c) + rows(d) + rows(e) + rows(f) + rows(g)),colIndex))))`

Comment: hmm - i suppose this is where a recursive lambda will come into play - but I haven't done that yet. Here is a good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7s6Dni1dG8 - but you need to have to be on the beta chanel of Microsoft 365

Comment: Ok, so I cannot hard code it with something like my example? The recursive lambda sounds great and very fancy and I'm fine with something dumb like what I tried to make

Comment: you can hard code it - but you will get a pretty unreadable and unmaintainable formula

Comment: I don't mind! Maybe this is beyond the scope for this answer though

Comment: It won't let me add the bounty for another day, but I will when I can